# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$2,464.34'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, excel

I am trying to convert the data to float in order make it as numerical format in excel to sort the data i am getting error.wherever the float in mentioned i did it now but previously there was no float .

```
 def get_output_value(self, key, value, neutral=None):
    display = value
    if value is None and not neutral.person.is_active:
        return '-', '-'

    if value is None:
        return float(f"${Decimal('.00')}"), float(f"${Decimal('.00')}")

    if isinstance(value, Decimal):
        return float(f"${intcomma(value.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}"), float(f"${intcomma(display.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}")

    return float(value), display
```

Comment: A `float`/`Decimal` or other numerical type does *not* "carry" a currency, hence that is not possible. Please share the mixin that is used to produce the excel file, since you can simply alter the formatting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the error message in this case. `'$2,464.34'` is a string with `$` and `,` characters in it, but `float()` expects a number-like input.

TLDR, you want `float('2464.34')` but you're giving `float('$2,464.34')`